# Python - How can I make this code asynchronous?

Tags: python, asynchronous, twisted, nonblocking, event-driven

Here's some code that illustrates my problem:

```
def blocking1():
    while True:
        yield 'first blocking function example'

def blocking2():
    while True:
        yield 'second blocking function example'

for i in blocking1():
    print 'this will be shown'

for i in blocking2():
    print 'this will not be shown'
```

I have two functions which contain `while True` loops. These will yield data which I will then log somewhere (most likely, to an sqlite database).

I've been playing around with threading and have gotten it working. However, I don't really like it... What I would like to do is make my blocking functions asynchronous. Something like:

```
def blocking1(callback):
    while True:
        callback('first blocking function example')

def blocking2(callback):
    while True:
        callback('second blocking function example')

def log(data):
    print data

blocking1(log)
blocking2(log)
```

How can I achieve this in Python? I've seen the standard library comes with asyncore and the big name in this game is Twisted but both of these seem to be used for socket IO.

How can I async my non-socket related, blocking functions?

Comment: `What I would like to do is make my blocking functions asynchronous` That doesn't make any sense. You either want your function to block, or you want it asynchronous. If you want it asynchronous, use a thread. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I want my blocking functions to be non-blocking

Comment: There are a lot of questions that need to be answered about how the execution of those functions is interleaved, not just with each other, but with all of the subsequent code that you run. This is what the operating system is for, and why you generally want to use a thread for something like that. 

Can you explain what you don't like about threading? This is exactly the sort of problem that threading was created to solve.

Comment: I suppose I don't like it because I'm not used to it. I've been playing around with it today and still don't quite understand what's happening. I'm more accustomed to the callback approach

Answer (score 33):

A blocking function is a function which doesn't return, but still leaves your process idle - unable to complete more work.

You're asking us to make *your* blocking functions non-blocking.  However – unless you're writing an operating system – *you* don't have any blocking functions.  You might have functions which block because they make calls to blocking system calls, or you might have functions which "block" because they do a lot of computation.

Making the former type of function non-blocking is impossible without making the underlying system call non-blocking.  Depending on what that system call is, it may be difficult to make it non-blocking without also adding an event loop to your program; you don't just need to make the call and have it not block, you also have to make another call to determine that the result of that call will be delivered somewhere you could associate it.

The answer to this question is a very long python program and a lot of explanations of different OS interfaces and how they work, but luckily I already wrote that answer on a different site; I called it [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/).  If your particular task is already [supported by a Twisted reactor](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/10.2.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.html), then you're in luck.  Otherwise, as long as your task maps to some existing operating system concept, you can extend a reactor to support it.  Practically speaking there are only 2 of these mechanisms: file descriptors on every sensible operating system ever, and I/O Completion Ports on Windows.

In the other case, if your functions are consuming a lot of CPU, and therefore not returning, they're not really blocking; your process is still chugging along and getting work done.  There are three ways to deal with that:

- separate threads
- separate processes
- if you have an event loop, write a task that periodically yields, by writing the task in such a way that it does some work, then asks the event loop to resume it in the near future in order to allow other tasks to run.

In Twisted this last technique can be accomplished in various ways, but here's a syntactically convenient trick that makes it easy:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.task import deferLater
from twisted.internet.defer import inlineCallbacks, returnValue

@inlineCallbacks
def slowButSteady():
    result = SomeResult()
    for something in somethingElse:
        result.workHardForAMoment(something)
        yield deferLater(reactor, 0, lambda : None)
    returnValue(result)
```

Comment: Great post.  Have spent the past few hours searching around the net for info on another Python Socket blocking issue and although this post pertains to a different context (mine is gevent/greenlets), it's a nice beginners overview of why a routine might block in the setting of Python.  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 12):

You can use generators for cooperative multitasking, but you have to write your own main loop that passes control between them.

Here's a (very simple) example using your example above:

```
def blocking1():
    while True:
        yield 'first blocking function example'

def blocking2():
    while True:
        yield 'second blocking function example'


tasks = [blocking1(), blocking2()]

# Repeat until all tasks have stopped
while tasks:
    # Iterate through all current tasks. Use
    # tasks[:] to copy the list because we
    # might mutate it.
    for t in tasks[:]:
        try:
            print t.next()
        except StopIteration:
            # If the generator stops, remove it from the task list
            tasks.remove(t)
```

You could further improve it by allowing the generators to yield new generators, which then could be added to tasks, but hopefully this simplified example will give the general idea.

Comment: This seems to be a nice solution. However, if the two generators were to use libpcap to listen on two separate interfaces and return the packets sniffed, would I lose packets due to only one generator returning at a given time?

Comment: @mike: Yes. If you are going to do something I/O related like packet sniffing, then using real treads is a better solution (unless the I/O library in question provides a native non-blocking API).

Comment: The real answer here depends on the specifics.  If you're doing blocking I/O calls and that's the problem, then you need to transform *those calls* so that they are no longer blocking.  You can't do anything to the rest of your code to make it asynchronous (without threads) unless you've got an event-driven version of those functions.  In other words, see Keith's answer, and "use twisted".

Answer (score 2):

The twisted framework is not just sockets. It has asynchronous adapters for many scenarios, including interacting with subprocesses. I recommend taking a closer look at that. It does what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use full OS threading, you might try [Stackless](http://www.stackless.com/), which is a variant of Python that adds many interesting features, including "microthreads". There are a number of good [examples](https://bitbucket.org/stackless-dev/stackless/wiki/Tasklets) that you will find helpful.

Comment: Seems interesting but I'd prefer to stick to using Python

Comment: I interpreted the intro text as it being an alternative Python interpreter. I'll take another look at it now. Cheers.

Comment: It is an alternative Python interpreter.  Also, it won't make any of your code non-blocking (even with microthreads).

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn’t blocking. blocking1() and it’s brother return iterators immediately (not blocking), and neither does a single iteration block (in your case).

If you want to “eat” from both iterators one-by-one, don’t make your program try to eat up “blocking1()” entirely, before continuing...

```
for b1, b2 in zip(blocking1(), blocking2()):
    print 'this will be shown', b1, 'and this, too', b2
```